# Object Leaked in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uuid

When i do "Build and analyze" XCode gives me the following warning:

**Potential leak of an object stored into 'string'**

```
- (NSString *)getUUID
{
NSString *UUID = [EA_APP_CONSTANT getUserDefaultsValueForKey:@"uniqueID"];
if (!UUID) {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    UUID = [(__bridge NSString*)string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];
    [EA_APP_CONSTANT setUserDefaultsValue:UUID forKey:@"uniqueID"];
}
return UUID;
}
```

How can i resolve this Problem?

Comment: You never release `string`.  But why are you doing this to begin with?  Why not `NSUUID.new.UTF8String;`?

Answer (score 0):

You need call `CFRelease(string);`

```
- (NSString *)getUUID
{
NSString *UUID = [EA_APP_CONSTANT getUserDefaultsValueForKey:@"uniqueID"];
if (!UUID) {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    UUID = [(__bridge NSString*)string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];
    [EA_APP_CONSTANT setUserDefaultsValue:UUID forKey:@"uniqueID"];

    CFRelease(string);
}
return UUID;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @iSashok its resolved it.

Comment: You are welcome! Please, mark your question as answered.